# changing String value based upon String[] index

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

i know how to do this

```
public class AccountPicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String password = "";
        String[] accounts = {"a", "b", "c"};

        Random r = new Random();
        int assigned = r.nextInt(3);

        if (assigned == 2) {
            password = "password";
            System.out.println("account: " + accounts[assigned] + " " + "password: " + password);
        }

        if (assigned == 1) {
            password = "Password";
            System.out.println("account: " + accounts[assigned] + " " + "password: " + password);
        }

        if (assigned == 0) {
            password = "PASSWORD";
            System.out.println("account: " + accounts[assigned] + " " + "password: " + password);
        }
    }
}
```

basically what this is doing is choosing a account `a, b , or c` and changing `password`  based upon which index was picked out of `accounts`

but what if i have 100 values in `accounts`?

making 100 if statements would take up too much code..

is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of passwords corresponding to each account e.g.:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class AccountPicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String password = "";
        String[] accounts = { "a", "b", "c" };
        String[] passwords = { "password", "Password", "PASSWORD" };

        Random r = new Random();
        int assigned = r.nextInt(3);

        System.out.println("account: " + accounts[assigned] + ", password: " + passwords[assigned]);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
account: c, password: PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1):

This task is especially suited for a `Map`.  So you can also do it like this.

```
    Map<String,String> accts = Map.of("a","password", "b", "Password", "c", "PASSWORD");
    System.out.println(accts.get("c"));
```

Prints

> PASSWORD

To see them all you can do it a variety of ways.

```
accts.forEach(System.out::println);
```

or

```
accts.forEach(e->System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " e.getValue());
```

Instead of giving you a number, they just provide the acct(or username). But use whichever is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically mapping a number to a String.  You could create an array of Strings, either hard-coded as you have or preferrably obtained from somewhere else, and then select a random value in that array.